# Align specific text in a table cell

Tags: tables

Im doing the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline
         myText\\\hline
         $F:x\mapsto c$ où $c\in\mathds{R}$ \\\hline
         $F:x\mapsto x+c$ où $c\in\mathds{R}$\\\hline
         $F:x\mapsto ax+c$ où $c\in\mathds{R}$\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And I wanted to know if it was possible to align the "où *c* in *R*" to the rightmost of the cell, while keeping all the other math to the leftmost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}\hline
         myText\\\hline
         $F:x\mapsto c \hfill $ où $c\in\mathds{R}$ \\\hline
         $F:x\mapsto x+c \hfill $ où $c\in\mathds{R}$\\\hline
         $F:x\mapsto ax+c \hfill $ où $c\in\mathds{R}$\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**OR**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|lr|}\hline
         myText&\\\hline
         $F:x\mapsto c$   & où $c\in\mathds{R}$\\\hline
         $F:x\mapsto x+c$ & où $c\in\mathds{R}$\\\hline
         $F:x\mapsto ax+c$& où $c\in\mathds{R}$\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i needed! tysm

Answer (score 0):

You may liked a quite different style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 rowsep = {7pt},
                 row{1} = {rowsep=4pt},
                 }
         myText             \\
    $
     \begin{rcases}
         F:x\mapsto c       \\
         F:x\mapsto x+c     \\
         F:x\mapsto ax+c    \\
     \end{rcases}   \text{ où } c\in\mathds{R}
    $     
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```